# TIN interpolation in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, tin

I am creating a new script in graphical modeler. I have an input which is « vector field » as point.

But when I use « TIN interpolation », I’m not able to select an « input of the model ». I can only select layers that are already loaded in QGIS, which is not very useful in graphical modeler!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing this problem in my model's development, currently, I'm using the Thin Plate Spline (TIN) algorithm as a replacement for QGIS' native TIN algorithm or the Multilevel B-Spline depending on my needs.

I think you should post a bug report as that's not the intended behavior.

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30029, as of 3.22.11 LTR this bug hasn't been resolved, the workaround is using SAGA TIN for a drop-in replacement (albeit with different result compared to the native algorithm).

Edit: I'm currently using `Triangulation [saga:triangulation]` from SAGA (https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/7.8.2/grid_gridding_5.html), which need a point layer. So, as an intermediate, I'm passing the vector layer to `Vector geometry -> Points along geometry [native:pointsalonglines]` with 2m spacing. Both works in model builder and result in an otherwise identical result (to the naked eye, and in my case, after converting back to contour line) to `qgis:tininterpolation`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @katagena adding additional information, you can use `saga:triangulation` as a drop-in replacement to `qgis:tininterpolation`. If your vector layer is a structure or break line, you will need to pass the layer to `native:pointsalonglines`. Both works in model builder.